# SQL - How To Add Rows Between a Range of Numbers and Make Their Value 0

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

[SQL Query I Am Working With](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWu2Q.png)

[Result from the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mcHk.png)

What I am trying to accomplish is that instead of just having values for places where num_opens is actually counted, I would want to have it show all potential num_opens values between the minimum and maximum value, and their total to be 0. For example, in the photo we see a jump between

num_opens: 7 Total: 1

num_opens: 10 Total: 1

**But I would like it to be**

num_opens: 7 Total: 1

num_opens: 8 Total: 0

num_opens: 9 Total: 0

num_opens: 10 Total: 1

and similarly for all potential num_opens values between the minimum and maximum (11 - 15, 15 - 31, 31 - 48). It is tricky because everyday the maximum value could be different (today the max is 48, but tomorrow it could be 37), so I would need to pull the max value somehow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_array()` and `unnest()`:

```
select num_opens, count(t.num_opens)
from (select min(num_opens) as min_no, max(num_opens) as max_no
      from t
     ) x cross join
     unnest(generate_array(t.min_no, t.max_no)) num_opens left join
     t
     on t.num_opens = num_opens
group by num_opens;
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference table to start with.  From your picture you have something called `users`, but really any (big enough) table will do.

So to start, you'll build the reference table using a `rank()` or `row_count()` function.  Or if your `users.id` has no gaps it's even easier to use that.

`SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY id) as reference_value FROM users`

This will generate a table `1....n` for `users`.

Now you join onto that, but count from the joined in table:

```
SELECT 
    a.reference_value, count(b.num_opens) as total
FROM   
     (SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY id) as reference_value from users) a
LEFT JOIN 
     [whatever table] b ON a.reference_value = b.num_opens
GROUP BY 
   a.reference_value
```

But this is too many rows!  You definitely have more users than these event counts.  So throw a quick filter in there.

```
SELECT 
    a.reference_value, count(b.num_opens) as total
FROM   
     (SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY id) as reference_value from users) a
LEFT JOIN 
     [whatever table] b ON a.reference_value = b.num_opens
WHERE
     a.reference_value <= (SELECT max(num_opens) FROM [whatever table])
GROUP BY 
   a.reference_value
```